# Passing values from Java to nsis script

Tags: java, nsis

I have a java code, where I give some variable dynamically. I need to pass that value to the nsis script. For example I will get a value of the variable age at runtime, and pass it to the var of the nsis script. Is it possible. Any suggestions...

Comment: can you provide little more details? Do you want to invoke a NSIS script from java and pass some variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I pass data to the NSIS script is with ant. When you build your installer you can place tokens in the NSI file and replace them. example using @product.name@ in the NSI file.:

```
  <replace file="${release.dir}/installer.nsi" token="@product.name@" value="${product.name}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read environment variables in NSIS files like this:

```
$%envVarName%
```

In addition, the ant task allows to set symbols directly:

```
<nsis script="myproject.nsi" verbosity="4" out="build.log" noconfig="yes">
    <define name="VERSION" value="2.1"/>
</nsis>
```